# why does the 2nd statement creates Assigning to non-lvalue '' main.c?

Tags: c, macros, lvalue, mikroc

hi whats the difference between these statements  given below?

```
 #define RES_WRITE 0Xf0f0
 #define DATA (0x0000 |= (1<<15))
 #define DATA (RES_WRITE |= (1<<15))
```

when DATA is assigned to a int variable it shows an error like "Assigning to non-lvalue.
may i know the reason behind this error and how to resolve the error what mistake i am doing?

Comment: `0x0000 |= (1<<15)` - what do you want to do here? You cannot write value to a literal.

Comment: `|=` is an assignment operator, just like `+=` is, except it does bitwise or instead of addition.     The expression `0 += 1` would give a similar diagnostic, for exactly the same reason - the left hand side of an assignment operator needs to be something that can be assigned to.

Comment: You probably just want `|` rather than `|=`

Comment: DATA basically expands to 0 = 1 << 15 i dont think so it will be equal to ‭0x8000 and thats what i want to mask the 15th bit only‬

Comment: MACRO are not statement, And unclear what you mean by *"when DATA is assigned"*.

Comment: @y0g1nder Not really, no. Little mistake. Actually it's equalt to `0 = 0 | (1 << 15)`, or `0 = 0 | 0x8000` if you want to resolve the shift first.

Comment: @Jarod42 i want to mask diffent bits and then assign all the bits to one variale like unsigned int var1 = DATA|0X00F0|0X0100;

Comment: Unrelated to the question, never write `1<<15` because that invokes undefined behavior on 8- or 16-bit systems. Use `1u<<15` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to send 0b1000000000000000 to a port of a microcontroller or globally to a buffer.
change |= to |

> why you faced error?

consider one of your macros:

```
#define DATA (0x0000 |= (1<<15))
```

in this macro, you try to do this:

```
0x0000 = 0x0000 | (1<<15))
```

is it possible to write data on *0x0000*?
*0x0000* is value; it means that it don't have any location on memory.

Comment: `1 << 15` is `0b1000'0000'0000'0000` (or `0x80'00`)  not `0x10'00'00'00'00'00'00'00` :).

Answer (score 1):

`x |= y` is the shorthand for `x = x | y`, so you end up with

```
0 = 0 | (1 << 15)
```

In this expression you are trying to assign something to a literal, which is not possible. Also the `|` is redundant, since `0 | x` is always just `x`.

From your comment *"i want to mask diffent bits and then assign all the bits to one variale"* it seems like you want simple constants that mask a single bit:

```
#define DATA (1 << 15)
```

which is a integral number with only 1 bit set, that can be used as a mask. For various reasons you should prefer `constexpr` over macros in modern C++:

```
constexpr unsigned DATA = 1 << 15;
```

You can use both like you mentioned

```
auto x = DATA | 0x00f0 | 0x0100;
```

Comment: I would prefer `unsigned` types for flag.